# What does a wallpaper with a clock mean?

Tags: icons, desktop-background, clock

I was changing my wallpaper and  I saw one with a clock on the lower right. I choice it and it was not there. So it is indicating it does something.

[image: Image of icon]

This is most likely me being blind.

Comment: It says below the Wallpaper that it "Changes throughout the day"

That's what the clock signifies. Wait and see, it'll probably change to a night scene at night time.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let me give you a hint:

[image]

> Changes throughout the day

This wallpaper will automatically cycle through all of the default wallpapers shipped with Ubuntu once every day.

Its behaviour is configured in a file `/usr/share/backgrounds/contest/*.xml`, with the file name normally being equal to your Ubuntu release name (e.g. `xenial.xml`).

Comment: You know, you can accept the answer that solved your question by clicking the grey round check button on its left? That way you mark your question as solved.

Comment: Ok sorry i am new to ubuntu. It is just... Windows crashes to much and Other Linux distros don't support my hardware. I only know steam,chrome / firefox, software center, sudo apt-get install (PACKAGE NAME)